# $\overline{Int(\overline{Int(A)})}=\overline{Int(A)}$

Tags: general-topology

> **Question:**
>
> Let $X$ be a topological space and let $A\subset X$ a subspace.
>
> a) Prove that $\overline{Int(\overline{Int(A)})}=\overline{Int(A)}$ .
>
> b) There exist a maximal open set $B$ such that $A$ is a dense set in it.

**My approach:**

For (a) I managed to prove that $\overline{Int(\overline{Int(A)})}\subseteq\overline{Int(A)}$ quite easily.

One must notice that $Int(\overline{Int(A)})\subseteq\overline{Int(A)}$,

thus, $\overline{Int(\overline{Int(A)})}\subseteq\overline{\overline{Int(A)}}=\overline{Int(A)}$, and it is finished.

The other side is much harder for me and I did not manage to come up with an idea.

For (b) I think that $B=Int(\overline{A})$. It is easy to see that A is a Dense set in it but I cannot prove that it is the maximal one.

Please help.

Comment: There is a "dual" result: Writing $\bar A$ as $Cl(A)$, we have $Cl(Int (Cl(Int(A))))=Cl(Int(A)).$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$Int(A) \subset \overline{Int(A)}$. The interior of a set is the union of all open sets contained in it, so then $Int(A) \subset Int(\overline{Int(A)}) \subset \overline{Int(\overline{Int(A)})}$. Taking the closure, $\overline{Int(A)} \subset \overline{Int(\overline{Int(A)})}$.

For (b), suppose $A$ is dense in an open set $U$. That means $U \subset \overline{A}$, and then since $U$ is open $U \subset Int(\overline{A})$.

Comment: why is $Int(A) \subset Int(\overline{Int(A)})$?

Comment: By definition, $Int(\overline{Int(A)})$ is the union of all open subsets of $\overline{Int(A)}$, one of which is $Int(A)$.

Comment: @Nathaniel Meyer , Or you can say that   $A\subset Y\implies Int(A)\subset Int(Y),$  with  $Y=\overline {Int(A)}.$ :)

Answer (score 1):

In the first of your question you have never used the definition of $Int(A)$.

$$Int(A)\subset \overline{Int(A)}$$ for obvious reasons. Since $Int(A)$ is open, it is contained in the maximal open subset of $\overline{Int(A)}$. Therefore,

$$Int(A)\subset Int(\overline{Int(A)}),$$
after that you obtain the second inclusion.